# Preform a CCAction after moving to each position in a NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Right now I have an NSArray containing tile coordinates that I wish a sprite to follow. The Sprite will "jump" to each coordinate and preform a CCAction before moving to the next coordinate in the array. I am unsure as to how to approach this. Any ideas?

Comment: [for-in loop?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html) (see Fast Enumeration Makes It Easy to Enumerate a Collection)

Comment: Could you please elaborate.

Comment: ```for (SomeCoord *coordinate in array) {
        [self.sprite moveToCoord:coordinate];
        [self.sprite doSomeCCAction];
}```  That help?

Comment: Doing that seems to make it jump to the last coordinate in the array then preform the action.

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates are correct (including their order) then?  for-loops enumerate arrays sequentially.

Comment: I know for a fact that the order is correct, it a pathfinding program. I must not be implementing the way you suggested properly.

Comment: If you run an action while another action is running, it will "overwrite" it. That's why I suggest a CCSequence.

Comment: Its not two actions, its setting the position and then running the action.

Comment: @CodaFi could you maybe expand, or just explain a little more your method so I can try to implement it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a CCSequence you can generate an action for every point to reach. My example supposes you're wrapping CGPoint, and it's pretty indicative, it will probably not do it what you're exactly looking for, but it's just to give you an idea:

```
// I suppose that you wrapped CGPoint with an object able to return the x and y coordinates.
// points contains all these coordinate objects.
NSMutableArray* actions= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity: points.count];
for(NSUInteger i=0; i<points.count; i++)
{
    id coordinate= points[i];
    CGPoint point= CGPointMake(coordinate.x, coordinate.y);
    // Change this code to whatever is needed to initialize the point.
    CCMoveTo* move= [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration: duration position: point];
    // I suggest to compute duration in a way that it depends from the speed, so
    // that the sprite moves with constant speed.
    [actions addObject: move];      
}
CCSequence* sequence= [CCSequence actionsWithArray: actions];
[sprite runAction: sequence];
```

I've typed it directly in the browser, I just hope there isn't some syntax error, let me know it in that case.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try this.

Comment: Just note that I haven't understood very well what you need to do. If you need to execute another type of action, just add it to the sequence instead of move. If you need to change a property I suggest to look at CCActionTween.

Comment: My goal is this: The sprite moves to point A, pauses for a set amount of time, then moves to point B, ...etc.